# How do you create a bank deposit using the Screen based API

Tags: acumatica

I am currently in need of automating the creation of bank deposits using the screen based API.

What would be the best way of doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how I managed to do it:

```cs
class Payment
{
    public string Module;
    public string Type;
    public string RefNbr;
    public decimal Amount;
}
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var paymentsToDeposit = new Payment[]
        {
            new Payment { Module = "AR", Type = "Payment", RefNbr = "000483", Amount = 100 },
            new Payment { Module = "AR", Type = "Payment", RefNbr = "000484", Amount = 200 },
        };

        Screen context = new Screen();
        context.CookieContainer = new System.Net.CookieContainer();
        context.Url = "http://localhost/bankDeposits/(W(53))/Soap/CA305000.asmx";
        context.Login("admin", "admin");

        Content bankDepositSchema = context.GetSchema();

        List<Command> commands = new List<Command>();
        commands.Add(new Value { Value = "<NEW>", LinkedCommand = bankDepositSchema.DepositSummary.ReferenceNbr });
        commands.Add(new Value { Value = "102000", LinkedCommand = bankDepositSchema.DepositSummary.CashAccount });
        commands.Add(new Value { Value = "test2", LinkedCommand = bankDepositSchema.DepositSummary.DocumentRef });
        commands.Add(new Value { Value = "OK", LinkedCommand = bankDepositSchema.AddPaymentToDeposit.ServiceCommands.DialogAnswer, Commit = true });

        decimal total = 0;
        foreach(Payment pmt in paymentsToDeposit)
        {
            commands.Add(new Key { Value = "='" + pmt.Module + "'", FieldName = bankDepositSchema.AddPaymentToDeposit.DocModule.FieldName, ObjectName = bankDepositSchema.AddPaymentToDeposit.DocModule.ObjectName });
            commands.Add(new Key { Value = "='" + pmt.Type + "'", FieldName = bankDepositSchema.AddPaymentToDeposit.Type.FieldName, ObjectName = bankDepositSchema.AddPaymentToDeposit.Type.ObjectName });
            commands.Add(new Key { Value = "='" + pmt.RefNbr + "'", FieldName = bankDepositSchema.AddPaymentToDeposit.ReferenceNbr.FieldName, ObjectName = bankDepositSchema.AddPaymentToDeposit.ReferenceNbr.ObjectName });
            commands.Add(new Value { Value = "True", LinkedCommand = bankDepositSchema.AddPaymentToDeposit.Selected, Commit = true });
            total += pmt.Amount;
        }

        commands.Add(bankDepositSchema.Actions.AddPayment);
        commands.Add(new Value { Value = total.ToString(System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture), LinkedCommand = bankDepositSchema.DepositSummary.ControlTotal });
        commands.Add(bankDepositSchema.Actions.Save);

        context.Submit(commands.ToArray());
        context.Logout();
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi @samol518 , thank you so much for adding this, it has helped me a lot in something similar. However, I am [hitting my head](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67152156/unable-to-select-multiple-shipments-on-process-form) on 'Selecting' multiple items on a Process form - do you perhaps have any tricks up your sleeve to address this issue? Once again, thanks for all you do in the Acumatica community!